# RangeError: Invalid Time Value after incorporating local storage

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a forum and using a form that the user fills out I'm storing data as an object inside an array. The data I'm storing includes the title of a topic, the message, the author and the date. That data is stored inside a `topic` array which I'm mapping on screen so the user can see all current topics, who created them and the date in which they were created. I also started to use localStorage so I can save my data and test to make sure everything looks good after my page refreshes.

```
const [topic, setTopic] = useState(() => {
  const topicJson = localStorage.getItem("topic");
  return topicJson ? JSON.parse(topicJson) : [];
});

const updatedTopic = [
      ...topic,
      {
        title: title,
        message,
        author: "Dagger",
        date: new Date(),
      },
    ];

    setTopic(updatedTopic);

  };
```

That's the code that I'm using which works as intended however when I map through the array to post the data on screen, I'm having trouble with showing the date. I'm using `date-fns` because it displays the date exactly how I want it.

Example: `2/19 9:39PM`. That's how I want the date to look on screen and using `date-fns` has been the only thing I've found that makes it look that way.

```
{topic
 .sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
 .map(({ date }, index) => (
   <tr>
      {<td>{format(date, "M/dd h:mma")}</td>}
   </tr>
))}
```

That's the code I'm using to map through the array to show the date. Before adding localStorage it worked fine. When I remove the `format` and show the code as `date` it works but including format gives me this error:

```
throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
// Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
// This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
```

Comment: My guess would be that when you JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse a date it is not longer in a date format but in a string format. You probably have to re-create a date object. Try replacing this line ```{<td>{format(date, "M/dd h:mma")}</td>}```with this one ```{<td>{format(new Date(date), "M/dd h:mma")}</td>}```

Comment: However if it works you will still probably have an issue with your sorting. So can you try without the .sort ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using Date object to store date and JSON.stringify cant handle Date object. You should to use Date method.

Easy way just save not Date object but ISO string.

date.toISOString()

And in table:

```
 {<td>{format(parseISO(date), "M/dd h:mma")}</td>}
```

Comment: Did you mean change `date` in the `topic` array to `date: new Date().toISOString(),`? I tried that and changed the table like you suggested and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you should save date in ISO string. And parse to readable date in UI